# how to share a windows printer (no wifi) with ubuntu?

Tags: windows, printing, sharing

I bought a printer which only has windows drivers. I installed these drivers on windows 10, it works fine, but I would like to be able to print from ubuntu 14.04 too, and I don't know if it is possible.
the printer is rather simple, it has no wifi, the only connection is by USB and it is connected to windows 10.

is it possible?

thanks
olivier

Comment: Converting non-answer to comment from @Android Dev. Please edit your question to include the make and model of the printer.

Comment: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77073/how-can-i-set-up-a-usb-printer-as-a-network-printer-using-a-linux-server for some tips on this

Answer (score 0):

You will still need a suitable Linux printer driver for that printer to use a printer shared via SMB/CIFS. It may be better to look for a Linux driver in the first place. Most printer models by the major manufacturers are supported unless they're brand new.